# Delete Zeroes from list of list

Tags: list-manipulation

I know how to delete zeros from a simple list, but I have a list like the following:

```
list11 ={{2,4,0,0,0},{3,0,0,0,0},{9,4,3,0,0}}
```

How do I delete the zeros from this and create a list like the following:

> {{2,4},{3},{9,4,3}}

Is this even possible since they have different lengths?

Comment: Have you seen [`DeleteCases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteCases.html)? You need the *levelspec* syntax.

Comment: @naomig: DeleteCases[{{2, 4, 0, 0, 0}, {3, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {9, 4, 3, 0, 
   0}}, 0, {2}]

Comment: Awesome, thanks!

Comment: You can also do it like this: DeleteCases[{{2, 4, 0, 0, 0}, {3, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {9, 4, 3, 0, 0}, {2, 4,
    0, 0, 0}, {3, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {9, 4, 3, 0, 0}, {2, 4, 0, 0, 0}, {3, 
   0, 0, 0, 0}, {9, 4, 3, 0, 0}, {2, 4, 0, 0, 0}, {3, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {9,
    4, 3, 0, 0}, {2, 4, 0, 0, 0}, {3, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {9, 4, 3, 0, 
   0}, {2, 4, 0, 0, 0}, {3, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {9, 4, 3, 0, 0}, {2, 4, 0, 0,
    0}, {3, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {9, 4, 3, 0, 0}}, 0, {-1}]

Comment: `DeleteCases[lst, 0, Infinity]` also seems to work.

Comment: In a list like `{9, 4, 0, 3, 0, 1}`, do you want the 0's to be deleted from it as well?

Comment: DeleteCases[{9, 4, 0, 3, 0, 1}, 0, {-1}]

Comment: With v10.2 or later: `{{2, 4, 0, 0, 0}, {3, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {9, 4, 3, 0, 0}} /. {0 -> Nothing}`

Comment: @BobHanlon And in earlier versions you can use `Sequence[]` instead of `Nothing`.

Answer (score 7):

According to the comments of [Nasser](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/70/nasser)

```
DeleteCases[list11, 0, Infinity]
```

> {{2,4},{3},{9,4,3}}

Answer (score 3):

Or instead of deleting the cases you don't want, you can select the cases you do want using [`UnequalTo`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UnequalTo.html):

```
Select[#, UnequalTo[0]] & /@ list11
{{2, 4}, {3}, {9, 4, 3}}
```

Comment: I've added a link in your answer because I didn't know and I found it very good